# Widgets overlap each other in the cells of table view swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I am getting widgets either `textField` or `textView` in cells of table view based on the provided elements in the array `widgetInstockArray`.
And getting placeholder for the widgets from the `labelInstcokArray`

The problem : The Cell appears with both widgets overlaped, the textField is enclosed within textView on every cell.

What I want : There should be a textField or textView in each cell but not both enclosed & overlapped simultaneously.

Here is what i have done so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextViewDelegate {

var widgetInstockArray = [String]()
var labelInstockArray = [String]()
var idInstockArray = [IntegerLiteralType]()
var newLabel = UITextField()
var newTextView = UITextView()
let wTextField = "textField"
let wTextView = "textView"

@IBOutlet weak var firstTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    widgetInstockArray = [wTextView, wTextField, wTextView, wTextField, wTextField, wTextView, wTextField]
    idInstockArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    labelInstockArray = ["1ok","2ok","3ok","4ok","5ok","6ok","7ok"]
    firstTableView.delegate = self
    firstTableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return widgetInstockArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
var Cell : UITableViewCell?

        var instockTag : Int = 1
        Cell = firstTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstCell")! as UITableViewCell
        if widgetInstockArray.count == 0 && labelInstockArray.isEmpty {
            print("no textFields in instock")
        }
        else {
            print("widget process i in winstock loop")
            for i in widgetInstockArray {
                print("widget process i in winstock loopok so here is \(i)")
                let indexOfA = widgetInstockArray.index(of: i)
                print("her is the index of i of widgets \(String(describing: indexOfA))")
                if i.contains(wTextField)  {
                    print("textField was placed")
                    newLabel = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 30))
                    newLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
                    newLabel.tag = instockTag
                    print("You have a instock textLabel with tag \(newLabel.tag)")
                    if labelInstockArray.isEmpty || idInstockArray.count != labelInstockArray.count {
                        newLabel.text = " "
                    } else {
                        newLabel.placeholder = labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
                        newLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 3
                        newLabel.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
                        newLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1
                        instockTag += 1
                        print("\(widgetInstockArray.count)")
                        Cell?.contentView.addSubview(newLabel)
                    }
                }

                if i.contains(wTextView) {
                    print("textView was placed")
                    newTextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 60))
                    newTextView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
                    newTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
                    newTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    newTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
                    newTextView.tag = instockTag
                    print("You have a instock textView with tag \(newTextView.tag)")
                    if labelInstockArray.isEmpty || idInstockArray.count != labelInstockArray.count {
                    } else {
                        //newTextView.text = labelInstockArray[indexPath.row]
                        newTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
                        newTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
                        newTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1
                        instockTag += 1
                        print("\(widgetInstockArray.count)")
                        Cell?.contentView.addSubview(newTextView)
                    }
                }
            }
            print("could not add widgets")
        }
    return Cell!
    }

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if newTextView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
        newTextView.text = nil
        newTextView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if newTextView.text.isEmpty {
        for i in labelInstockArray {
        newTextView.text = i
        }
        newTextView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Output is overlapped :( 
The textFiled is within the textview, both appear in a single cell.
But I want they should not overlap and there should be only one widget in each cell.

[image]

**UPDATE according to [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50270702/widgets-overlap-each-other-in-the-cells-of-table-view-swift-ios/50430656#50430656)**

What if i want to add widgets on a button click so live the widgets should be added on each click.

here is what i have done

```
var idWidgetIs = IntegerLiteralType()
var labelWidget = String()
var widgetName = String()

let stockArray: [StockItem] = [ StockItem(id: idWidgetIs, label: labelWidget, widget: widgetName)]

    @IBAction func textViewAct(_ sender: Any) {
    idWidgetIs += 1
    labelWidget = "placeholder"
    StockItem.init(id: idWidgetIs, label: labelWidget, widget: .textView)
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldAct(_ sender: Any) {
    idWidgetIs += 1
    labelWidget = "placeholder"
    StockItem.init(id: idWidgetIs, label: labelWidget, widget: .textField)
   }
```

Comment: Your question is not quite clear to me. What you trying to achieve  ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya i want there should be only single widget instead od overlapped both widgets as explained in snapshot

Comment: Got it now check my answer

Comment: Adding item in cell is not proper way, instead use hide/show mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As identified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50323380/1568889):

- every time the table view requests a cell, a new text field / text view is created
- looping through *widgetInStockArray* when creating a cell will result in multiple text fields and text views being added to that cell

The sample code from the question can be restructured and improved as follows to achieve the desired result.

---

#### Restructure stock information

Define two types for more convenient access to the id, label and widget of a single stock item.

```
enum StockWidget: String {
    case textField
    case textView
}

struct StockItem {
    let id: IntegerLiteralType
    let label: String
    let widget: StockWidget
}
```

Update the sample data accordingly.

```
let stockArray: [StockItem] = [
    StockItem(id: 1, label: "1ok", widget: .textView),
    StockItem(id: 2, label: "2ok", widget: .textField),
    StockItem(id: 3, label: "3ok", widget: .textView),
    StockItem(id: 4, label: "4ok", widget: .textField),
    StockItem(id: 5, label: "5ok", widget: .textField),
    StockItem(id: 6, label: "6ok", widget: .textView),
    StockItem(id: 7, label: "7ok", widget: .textField)
]
```

#### Define specific cells

One with a `UITextField`:

```
class TextFieldWidgetCell: UITableViewCell {

    let textField: UITextField

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        let field = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 30))
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        field.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        field.textColor = UIColor.gray
        textField = field

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(textField)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        textField.placeholder = nil
        textField.text = nil
    }

}
```

and one with a `UITextView`:

```
class TextViewWidgetCell: UITableViewCell {

    let textView: UITextView

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
        let view = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 60))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
        view.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.justified
        view.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView = view

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.addSubview(textView)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        textView.text = nil
    }

}
```

Register the widget cells with the table view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstTableView.dataSource = self
    firstTableView.delegate = self

    firstTableView.register(TextFieldWidgetCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StockWidget.textField.rawValue)
    firstTableView.register(TextViewWidgetCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: StockWidget.textView.rawValue)
}
```

#### Adapt `UITableViewDataSource` implementation

Now that the cell configuration is split off into two `UITableViewCell` subclasses, the implementation of `tableView(_, cellForRowAt:)` can be reduced a great deal.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stockArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let stockItem = stockArray[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: stockItem.widget.rawValue)

    switch stockItem.widget {
    case .textField:
        if let cell = cell as TextFieldWidgetCell {
            cell.textField.placeholder = stockItem.label
        }
    case .textView:
        if let cell = cell as TextViewWidgetCell {
            cell.textView.text = stockItem.label
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: please see my updated question, whether i can add widgets on a button click?

Answer (score 4):

### **Problems**

1) **You are programatically adding subview. as cell is reused so you are creating TextField and TextView Every time**

2)  **One more problem I am seeing in your code is  `i.contains(wTextField)`

 and `i.contains(wTextView)` that will be always true  as both of `wTextField` and  `wTextView` are in the array `widgetInstockArray` and both frame is `CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 30)` so  you are getting it overlapped**

---

### Better Solution is to use `UIStackView`

Create custom cell with `UIStackview`

Now add One `UITextField` and one `UITextView`  to `UIStackview` .

Now next step is in `cellForRow` Method. Just hide the other element like

```
if i == wTextField  { 
  cell.wTextView.isHidden = true
   cell.wTextField.isHidden = false

} else {
  cell.wTextField.isHidden = true
  cell.wTextView.isHidden = false

}
```

When you hide one of view in `UIStackView` other element automatically set accordingly

Hope it is helpful, Please let me know in case of Queries

**UPDATE**

Not related but it is not good practice to keep two array to fill tableview it might be problematic for future update code.

Better solution would be create `struct` or `class`

Like

```
enum Widget {
    case TextField
    case TextView
}
struct StockArray {
    var type : Widget
    var labelInstockArray = [String]()
    var idInstockArray = [IntegerLiteralType]()
}
```

Now You can create array of `StockArray` and it is very easy to maintain

Bingo !!!

Comment: @iOSDeveloper i have updated my answer with proper description

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Check my suggestion

Comment: let me implement your answer

Comment: I supposed `if i.contains(textField)` checks only the single value which is at the index of `i` so it can be either textField or TextView isn't it?

Comment: outlet is not creating of Stackview to a table view cell but in VC so how can i define evrything in that?

Comment: suppose I want to make an outlet of stackview to a table view and adding subviews but how can i get outlet of them as they are not getting due to stack is not being connected to table view cell

Comment: No you can't have outlet in ViewController , You have to take it in tableview cell only, However you can access cell from tableview with indexPath or index, You should read some tutorials  so you can get clear idea on it.

Comment: outlet is not being connected with table view cell of stack view

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Make sure in xib or storyboard you have properly set class

Comment: set the class bro i forgot that

Comment: `Cell?.wTextField.isHidden = true` is not working as it warns about the time `Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'wTextField'`, should i add as cell.stackview.wtextFiled.ishidden=true?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper it will take full week to explain small problems , Please read some tutorial or watch video about **how to use custom cell in swift4**

Comment: @Parshant my method of doing is working fine upto 6 widgets when i add 7th widget the y started overlapping and appear both textField and textView I dont know this myth?

Comment: I have added the widgets in Stackview but when i hide the textView the textField appear double the size occuying its own space as well as textView space ? shoul i place both widget in sigle stack or for every widget there should be another stack so i can hide and show stacks??

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code/need correctly, adding subview is a **not** problem for overlap. **Adding subviews multiple times** is the problem

`for i in widgetInstockArray {` line in `cellForRowAt` method is the problem. Basically for each cell you are looping through `(7 times = 3 for wTextView and 4 for wTextField)` which means you are adding view over the view.

Suggestion: Remove `for i in widgetInstockArray {` and

```
 let i = widgetInstockArray[indexPath.row]
```

and compare using

```
 if i == wTextField {
```

and similarly for wTextView.